# How to calculate a private key from public key on elliptic curve?

Tags: cryptography, elliptic-curve

Provided, that you have to multiply a well known G by the private key to obtain the public key, why not keep adding G to itself until you reach the public key. The private key should be the number of times you've added the G to itself. Is it correct? And if so - why isn't it feasible?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not involve programming. It is a pure cryptography question and therefore should be posted e.g. on https://crypto.stackexchange.com

Comment: There are better algorithms that have a complexity that's the square root of the complexity of your algorithm. So elliptic curve cryptosystems are designed so that the square root of group order is at least 2^128. That's why it's infeasible.

Answer (score 0):

why breaking a complexity of 2^128 is highly unlikely?

look at the odds ...

winning the mega millions jackpot with a single ticket 1 / 258890850
doing that 4 times in a row ... 1 / 280767492220503717482331687890625

which is still ~75748 times more likely than guessing a 1/(2^128) chance right...

if you would run your algorithm and simply start adding and counting, you'd have to do that a lot...

let's say you can go through 2^40 iterations per day ... how long would you need to do that to get a 50% chance of finding the key?

for 50% you'd need to search half of the keyspace ... half of 2^128 ... which is 2^127 ... if you can go through 2^40 per day, you would need 2^127 / 2^40 = 309485009821345068724781056 days ...

309485009821345068724781056 days... that are 847904136496835804725427 years and 201 days ... the 50% goal would be reached after 847904136496835.8 billion years ... sadly our sun only has an estaminated main sequence lifespan of 10 billion years ...

in other words ... whoopsy